# What is the so-called "variance" of error?

Tags: regression, linear-model

Take linear regression model - OLS method for instance.
$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X + u$

Assume there is a data frame of 2 column X, Y, and 500 rows of values of X and Y.

There is an assumption "constant error variance", i.e.
$V(u_1)=V(u_2)=...=V(u_{500})=\sigma^2$

So, I wonder what does something like $V(u_1)$ mean? Each pair $(x_1, y_1)$ yields only 1 value for $u_1$, so how $V(u_1)$ makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming that all of the variance is due to the Y value.

An example: You set your instrument to 10 V, and the output is 27 jiggles per second. With this method, we assume that the 10 V is 10.000000... V, and that any deviation of the data from the model is due to the 27 j/s moving around. If I do some more measurements, and come back to 10 V again, maybe the output is 29 j/s.

You can do the analysis where you assume a constant variance for all y values, different variance for all y values, and a model where both x and y have some variance (see York et al. (2004). Unified equations for the slope, intercept, and standard errors of the best straight line. Am.J. Phys. 72(3): 367-375.)